# Quest Diagnostics PHP Soap Solution

Tags: php

Has anyone ever used PHP to connect to Quest Diagnostics Soap webservice?  They only have .net and java examples and I need a PHP solution and do not know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with php and if you have the WSDL URL then you should generate the PHP sdk from the WSDL which will you ease you the request construction ans the response handling.

Try the PackageGenerator project from Github ;)